# MySQL - Why does the same stored procedure execute in a different time?

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures

In MySQl, I was inspecting an amount of time my stored procedure will need to perform. To test it, I did the following:

```
#1
mysql> call getSnowTemp(3,0);
9 rows in set (2.12 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (2.13 sec)

#2
mysql> call getSnowTemp(3,0);
9 rows in set (1.90 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.92 sec)

#3
mysql> call getSnowTemp(3,0);
9 rows in set (1.65 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.67 sec)

#4
mysql> call getSnowTemp(3,1);
13 rows in set (1.56 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.58 sec)

#5
mysql> call getSnowTemp(3,2);
7 rows in set (0.84 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.85 sec)

#6
mysql> call getSnowTemp(3,3);
2 rows in set (0.73 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.74 sec)

#7
mysql> call getSnowTemp(3,0);
9 rows in set (0.63 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.64 sec)
```

I observed the behaviour that I was not expecting and the following questions arised:

1. Why do the execution of #1, #2 and #3 are giving us the different execution time?
2. Why does the execution of all the stored procedure have an "improving trend" meaning that by every next execution, it will be performed in a shorter time (meaning in the same MySQL session, I expect after logging out and in it will again show the same behaviour as explained above)? (Compare execution of #3 with #7)

If needed, I can provide a query for the stored procedure, although I think it does not really relate to the problem. NOTE: During the test, the table on which the stored procedure was peformed remained the same (meaning no rows were inserted).

Comment: Because computers do more than one thing at the same time? And MySQL has cache and RAM and so?

Comment: Possibly it can be a reason, that's why I am asking. But still, the difference between #1 and #7 is quite big.

Comment: I have the impression that you've simply haven't expressed clearly the real question you have in mind. It's just physically impossible to get the same performance figures running a task twice, esp. a short task that runs once each time. All the executions are on similar ranges (it's not like you get 2 ms, 5 min, 30 s...). Disk access is several orders of magnitude slower than RAM access. Computer systems use all sort of intermediate caches. MySQL implements a memory buffer. To inspect performance you need a lot of info: SQL code, table structure, data volume, execution plan, profiling data...

Comment: OK, thank you for some explanation. So what I described in my question is from your point of view nothing special, but rather a normal behavior?